# How can I use fromdate and todate parameters in the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: stackexchange-api

I am using the Stack Exchange API to get the number of all unanswered questions in a particular tag. I am trying to create a table which shows the change in value over a period of time. Therefore, I am using `fromdate` and `todate`. The issue is that my result is varying slightly.

Setting `todate` to [`2020-07-01`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/unanswered?fromdate=2009-01-01&todate=2020-07-01&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=matlab&site=stackoverflow&filter=total) returns a total of 23517 questions, but as of now, the site shows 23526 in the [unanswered tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab?tab=Unanswered).

Comment: Why is that even important to you? A +/-0.03% deviation seems pretty irrelevant to me for purposes of statistical evaluation. My first suspicion would be a timezone difference, btw.

Comment: This works as intended. 2020-07-01 means 2020-07-01 00:00:00 UTC. If you want to get all the unanswered questions, remove from date and todate. If you only remove todate, then you will get questions from 2009-01-01 00:00:00 UTC to the time you make the API call.

Comment: @double-beep the reason to use todate is because I want historical data. And only way i could think about doing it is by may be keeping the fromdate fixed and change the todate.

Comment: @taschi i thought so too. However, this deviation is across various tags. Curious to know

Comment: todate takes either a day in the format YYYY-MM-DD or a number which is the number of secs (not millisecs!) elapsed from Jan 1st, 1970. You can generate that kind of date and work with that.

Answer (score 0):

Both `todate` and `fromdate` accept two types of arguments:

- Dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD, (which are actually YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00 UTC). You can also pass HH:MM:SS, which is optional.
- Dates in Unix epoch time (number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970 00:00:00 UTC).

Without a `todate` parameter, API returns the unanswered [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) questions from `fromdate` to the time the API call was made.

You, however, pass a fromdate in YYYY-MM-DD, which appears to be some hours earlier and hence the difference in the numbers.

Reference: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/dates